# Unable to getChart from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, spreadsheet

When i click to on button to execute script to send email, there is pop up saying

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

The line:  `var charts = sheet.getCharts();`

My script:

```
  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();


  var chartBlobs = new Array(charts.length); 
  var emailBody = "Charts<br>";
  var emailImages = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var builder = charts[i].modify();
    builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
    var newchart = builder.build();
    chartBlobs[i] = newchart.getAs('image/png');
    emailBody += "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart" + i + "'></p>";
    emailImages["chart" + i]= chartBlobs[i];
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email",
    subject: "ukol",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages: emailImages});
```

My whole file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qq9JhqguSuyTPmLLbI0Guoe5wcBx6n07EyRCCT_Pt8g/edit

Comment: I just copy this script from thsi site and it should work  like everybody says but i get this error i dont why

Comment: i am sorry i am not that good at programming but i though this should work. Anyway i tried to debug and it writes there is error var charts = sheet.getCharts(); , but i dont dont what error. There should be array and i am working with it like an arrays

Comment: Try with a brand new spreadsheet and just a single chart or no charts to start with. If nothing still works then may be raise a bug at https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/ I tried creating a sheet and getCharts worked fine for me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130176/sheet-getcharts0-returning-an-error-message